# google earth engine: access ImageCollection features list?

Tags: google-earth-engine

the console gives me a view into the 'properties' of the ImageCollection object:

```
ImageCollection LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR (107 elements)
type: ImageCollection
id: LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR
version: 1524816484446982
bands: []
features: List (107 elements)
properties: Object (23 properties)
```

and the docs describe methods to access the properties of the properties object.

problem: how do I read the features list? I want the 'id' property of each of the images (which the console can show me). I have tried:

```
var imageList = myImageCollection.toList(100).features;
```

and the error is: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

hoping for an undocumented method, I tried:

```
var imageList = myImageCollection.features();
```

and the error is: myImageCollection.features is not a function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the ID of an image using [ee.Image.id()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageid). For example:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-112.62, 40.98]);

var myImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

// Create a list of image objects.
var imageList = myImageCollection.toList(100);
print('imageList', imageList);

// Extract the ID of each image object.
var id_list = imageList.map(function(item) {
  return ee.Image(item).id();
});
print('id_list', id_list);
```

Comment: thank you, Tyler. (as one of the ee training audience members said, maybe this is an opportunity for more API sugar?)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my post here.

I am trying to filter out all stripping artifact bands in Landsat 5 surface reflectance for my study area, but I can't filter them automatically. Please help me, here is my code [here][1].


  [1]: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea4af1ee892e750a5d659850573b4af2