# When adding properties to an image, no longer allowed to add to Map

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, metadata

If I create an image, that I add properties to, I can no longer add the image to the Map.  How can I add it, or how can I add properties so that it doesn't break?

```
var myPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([-64.9823, -36.4917]);

var myArea = myPoint.buffer(5000);

var myImage = ee.Image(1).clip(myArea);

Map.centerObject(myImage);
Map.addLayer(myImage); // This works fine.


var myImageWithProperties = myImage.setMulti({
  Name: "ones",
  ID: 1234
}); 

Map.addLayer(myImageWithProperties); // after adding properties
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some functions in Google Earth Engine make the object 'loose' its type. If you have a look at `setMulti` documentation, it says that returns an `Element` not an `Image`. So you have to tell Earth Engine what it is (this is called "cast a variable").

```js
var myImageWithProperties = myImage.setMulti({
  Name: "ones",
  ID: 1234
});

// cast it
myImageWithProperties = ee.Image(myImageWithProperties)
```

Comment: So even if a function is under the Image section of the docs, it can make a an object 'lose' the type.  Strangely, when I print it to the console, it still is an image type.  But I made the suggested changes to the code, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot know how Earth Engine works internally, but to me, what happens is that `setMulti()` is an `ee.Element` method, and that is why it returns an `Element`. `ee.Image` and `ee.Feature` are subclasses of `ee.Element`

Comment: Understood.  In any case, the solution is as you suggested, Casting it to ee.Image.

Comment: @rodrigo-e-principe, really helpful answer, thanks!