# How to define/add image id in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is a very basic question in Google Earth Engine. 
I have an image converted from an ImageCollection using toBands():

```
Image = ee.ImageCollection(somelist.map(somefunction)).toBands()
```

Now I need to export this image to Asset. However, the metadata of this image only contains "type" and there is no "id". If I do

```
print(Image.id().getInfo())
```

the output is null. How can I specify the id by adding this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `.id()`, also known as the property `'system:index'`, is to an identify an image **within the collection it came from.**

You *could* set it on an image object, during a computation only, by setting the property named `'system:index'`, but there is little point in doing that, because it will not be saved to an exported asset, and if you ever put the image in a collection then it will be given a new `.id()`.

If you want to control the *asset ID* of an image, which is not the same as the context-dependent identifier `.id()` returns, you should use the `assetId` parameter of `Export.image.toAsset`.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Your explanation makes a lot of sense for a person new to the GEE structure! Setting "system:index" will give me a new `.id()` (exactly what I want), while setting 'id', the 'id' will be under "property" entry. The reason I want to control the `.id()` is originally because I want to batch export images in one collection. I am using a batch export tool from here: users/fitoprincipe/geetools. The batch export tool actually requires `.id()` to automatically set the assetID.

Comment: @pitcheverlasting Thanks for providing context! It would have been good to put that information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply obtained by setting the "system:index":

```
Image = somelist.map(function(x) x.set("system:index": something))
```

In the case of `toBands()`, it can be important to do it, since in absence of an image id, `toBands()` will add numeric indices to the band names. This can cause a conflict when exporting:

> Error: Band ID "0_prcp_mean_2000_1" is invalid. Band IDs must **start**
> **with a..z or A..Z** and must contain only the following characters:
> a..z, A..Z,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like band names starting with a number are not valid when exporting images as assets. Before exporting your image, you can rename the bands, prefixing them with a letter:

stack.regexpRename('^(.*)', 'b_$1')